# problems retrieving db 'note' info to display in styled html divs through php, JSON, query and sql

Tags: php, jquery, sql, arrays, json

I'm trying to:

1. take a 'note' and its id which is stored in a mysql db (where it matches a username)
2. use PHP and store it in an array
3. use JSON to make it manageable for the client side processing.
4. take each individual note instance with associated note id info.
5. display each note in a separate html div for CSS styling
6. do it in a way which lets each note in its div be deleted by the user (from the db)

The sql is successful and I can retrieve the notes and display them in the form:

> "This is note one"
> "This is note two"

but obviously this doesn't allow for steps 4, 5 and 6 (which is where I'm having problems - how do I take all of this and turn it into something useful for creating a new div for each 'note')

```
$sql = "SELECT note FROM notes WHERE username = '$uname'";
//below is for the next step where I want to also retrieve the note's id
//$sql = "SELECT * FROM notes WHERE username = '$uname'";
$result = mysql_query($sql,$conn);
$i = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $notes[$i] = $row['note'];
    echo json_encode($notes[$i]);

    $i += 1;
}
```

I've looked into parse, jquery and even arrays after arrays but I'm totally lost now, so help towards this would be massively appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the jquery for creating a new div:

[jQuery create new div with ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5314537/jquery-create-new-div-with-id)

This is seems like a good solution for client side information retrieval from my php array:

http://www.jquery4u.com/json/ajaxjquery-getjson-simple/

If I can work out the other steps I'll post links for later visitors.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure you've asked a question. But here's a couple of thoughts:

Unless $notes is going to be a memory hog (e.g. more than 10,000 rows), you should encode the entire set at once; what you are doing now is creating a bunch of JSON array, but you haven't enclosed them in any parseable structure. If you look at the output of this script, you'll see what I mean. For example:

Your script creates something like this:

```
{"one": 1, "two": 2, "three": 3}
{"one": 1, "two": 2, "three": 3}
{"one": 1, "two": 2, "three": 3}
```

You want something contained in a single object like this:

```
{ // enclosing structure
    {"one": 1, "two": 2, "three": 3}, //elements separated by commas
    {"one": 1, "two": 2, "three": 3},
    {"one": 1, "two": 2, "three": 3}
}
```

So try...

```
$sql = "SELECT note FROM notes WHERE username = '$uname'";
//below is for the next step where I want to also retrieve the note's id
//$sql = "SELECT * FROM notes WHERE username = '$uname'";
$result = mysql_query($sql,$conn);
$rows = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $rows[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($rows, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

Or, if you think this will exhaust available memory, then something like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT note FROM notes WHERE username = '$uname'";
//below is for the next step where I want to also retrieve the note's id
//$sql = "SELECT * FROM notes WHERE username = '$uname'";
$result = mysql_query($sql,$conn);
$i = 0;
echo "{";
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    if( $i++ > 0 ) { echo ",\n"; }
    echo json_encode($row);
}
echo "}";
```

Additionally, your script should include proper headers. It may function without, but these will save you some headaches:

```
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

Comment: Great, lots to look through, I will get on it. With regards to my question, the problem I have is trying to take the stuff in each array index and turn it into a format that I can use in a div but retain the ability for the user to delete. I realise that may be many steps ahead but I wanted to make sure that any responses were aimed down the correct path. Thanks again. I'll start trying.